# Where can i put the default value for parameters?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, arguments, declaration

When defining a function,can i specify a default value in the first parameter?     When i put the default value in the first parameter, I found Error. is there a  way to put the default value in the first parameter.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sum ( int a =42, int b)
{
    int result a +b ;
    return ( result ) ;
}
int main()
{
    int x = 25 ;
    int y = 23 ;
    int result = sum (x, y ) ;
    cout << result << endl;
}
```

Comment: An alternative would be to have a overload for `sum` with only 1 argument which returns `sum(42, b);`.

Comment: How do you expect to pass the value of `b`, without passing the value of `a` (while using the default value for it)?

Comment: That you got an error is a pretty solid hint that it can't be done. Use an overload.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius one could imagine a language where `sum( , b)` is valid (and takes the default value for `a`. But that's not possible in C++ ...

Answer (score 0):

To supply a default argument for the first parameter you have at first to supply a default argument for the second parameter.

For example

```
int sum ( int a, int b = 0 );

int sum ( int a = 42, int b)
{
    int result = a + b ;
    return ( result ) ;
}
```

Or just

```
int sum ( int a = 42, int b = 0 )
{
    int result = a + b ;
    return ( result ) ;
}
```